# How do I test for solar irradiation variation from 400-1000 W/m2?

Tags: power-electronics, mppt

I am new to the field of power electronics. I model maximum power point tracking perturb and observe algorithm with a buck-boost converter.

I want to test for various solar irradiance, please how do I go about this?

I want to test for various solar irradiation to be able to obtain the voltage, current and power, how can I do this?

I also don't know if my c-script for the MPPT is right or wrong.

I have obtained the IV and PV curve for the PV module used. It remains how I want to test for various solar irradiation from 400-1000 W/m^2 This is the link to my model which you can paste on browser and download. The model can only be opened with plecs software.

https://forum.plexim.com/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=7603544605438125951

Comment: Pretty narrow a range.

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing this for a space mission (HETE-2) a quarter of a century ago, I bought a "solar array simulator power supply". You program it with the characteristics of your panel. I can't recommend a current product, but they are easy to find with a search engine.